# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in src there is a package named random_husky_driver including:
CMakeLists.text    package.xml      random_driver.cpp

This is the cmakelists.text:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(random_husky_driver)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

set(random_driver ${random_drivers.cpp})
set(random_driver ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )
```

When I run catkin_make it gives me no error. BUT MY PROBLEM IS WHEN I RUN rosrun random_husky_driver random_driver I RECEIVE THIS ERROR:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named random_driver below /home/denso/ros101/src/random_husky_driver
```

I would appreciate it if you help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215932/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable-named-.../) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is the full `CMakeLists.txt`, the problem is simply that you are not building the respective node.

This package actually seems to be a [tutorial from Clearpath](https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/articles/201644249-Creating-a-workspace-package-and-publisher).

Check the `Compiling ...` section on how to compile anything.
You need to have the two following lines in there:

```
add_executable(random_driver random_driver.cpp)
target_link_libraries(random_driver ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

And the two lines with `set(...)` in your `CMakeLists.txt` don't make sense.

---

EDIT:

Two possibilities:

1. You don't have `costmap_2d` installed, do with `sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-costmap-2d` and replace `DISTRO` with whatever ROS version you are using.
2. You don't configure `CMake` correctly. Do you have something like `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS costmap_2d <otherpackages>)` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, together with the resepctive `include_dirs(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `target_link_libraries(..)` calls? And you need to declare it as a `<build_depend>` in the `package.xml`.

If this does not help, please update your question with the respective/new `CMakeLists.txt` content...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-18**:
i still getting this error

```
map_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [relaxed_astar/CMakeFiles/relaxed_astar_lib.dir/src/RAstar_ros.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [relaxed_astar/CMakeFiles/relaxed_astar_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-19**:
see edit above...

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
Thank you my problem was solved but i have another error after following this tutorial   [link text](http://www.iroboapp.org/index.php?title=Adding_Relaxed_Astar_Global_Path_Planner_As_Plugin_in_ROS)
the error is

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'turtlebot_navigation/
```

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-19**:
in the tutorial go all the way down where say { Running the Plugin on the Turtlebot }

Thank you for your time MIG

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-20**:
again, please as new question with more information

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-08-20**:
Would you please answer my question[CLICK HERE PLEASE](http://answers.ros.org/question/216229/rviz-robot-model-error/) in this link